# Обновление записей в БД при связи многие ко многим

Tags: sql, postgresql

Изучаю SQL. У меня есть таблица `products_to_colors` она связывает 2 таблицы `colors` и `products`, связь многие ко многим. Содержит поля `id` (просто `id` записи в таблице, хз зачем сделал эту колонку), `product_id`, `color_id`

```
 id | color_id | product_id
----+----------+-----------
1   | 1        | 7
----+----------+-----------
2   | 2        | 7
----+----------+-----------
3   | 3        | 7
----+----------+-----------
4   | 4        | 7
```

Столкнулся с задачей обновления данных в этой БД. Представим, что пришёл новый запрос и у продукта изменились цвета, например, продукт с id 7, теперь должен иметь цвета `[1, 3, 5, 7]`, было `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. Не могу написать адекватный SQL запрос для такой задачи. Конечно можно пройтись с помощью 2 циклов и ЯП (языка программирования) (1 цикл удаляет, 2 добавляет), сделав кучу запросов к БД, но это какой-то говнокод и никакой оптимизации, я так делать не хочу.

Скорее всего должно быть 2 запроса к БД, первый удаляет ненужные связи из `products_to_colors`, второй добавляет необходимые.

С запросом для удаления связей вроде как всё более менее понятно, сделал так (не знаю насколько это правильно):

```
DELETE FROM products_to_colors
    WHERE color_id = ANY (
            SELECT color_id FROM products_to_colors WHERE product_id=7
        )
        AND color_id != ANY('{1,3,5,7}')
        AND product_id=7;
```

Остаётся функция добавления связей с цветами, которых до этого не было. Тут я никак не соображу, что делать. Ну я могу пройтись по массиву со списком id цветов с помощью ЯП и проверить, есть ли нужная связь в БД, если нет, то добавлять. Но это опять куча запросов и какой-то говнокод.

Нашёл [такой пост](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41295572/how-do-i-insert-into-a-table-values-from-two-arrays-in-postgres) но там немного другая ситуация, не знаю как это адаптировать к моей задаче. По SQL (особенно postgres) очень мало информации в интернете, особенно примеров. Не понятно как учиться писать хороший код =)

Comment: 1) Зачем Вы вообще упоминаете таблицы `colors` и `products`? они в принципе не нужны для решения задачи. 2) Как выглядят исходные данные ТОЧНО. "какие-то удались, какие-то добавились" - это ни о чём.

Comment: @Akina ок, щас подредактирую =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге решил задачу так:

```
DELETE FROM products_to_colors
WHERE color_id IN (
        SELECT color_id FROM products_to_colors WHERE product_id={product_id}
    )
    AND color_id != ALL({new_colors})
    AND product_id={product_id};

INSERT INTO products_to_colors (color_id, product_id)
    SELECT el, {product_id} FROM unnest({new_colors}) AS el WHERE el NOT IN (
        SELECT color_id FROM products_to_colors WHERE product_id={product_id}
    );
```

Где: `{new_colors}` - новые цвета, которые должны быть привязаны к продукту, `{product_id}` - id продукта

Comment: А почему просто не удалить все записи для указанного продукта? на что этот геморрой с дополнительными проверками при удалении?

Comment: @Akina ну зачем удалять записи, а потом заново их создавать? А если там 10.000 записей и надо только 1 запись добавить. Мне что сначала все удалять, а потом добавлять? Это же не оптимально

Comment: *А если там 10.000 записей* Для одного продукта? *надо только 1 запись добавить* Добавить? А в тексте вопроса Вы говорите о том, что Вы получаете новое состояние, а не изменение текущего... Вы уж определитесь, что ли...

Comment: @Akina ну вот были у продукта цвета с id `1, 2, 3 ... 10000`, а стали `1,2,3 ... 10001`. Получается добавился новый цвет, мой запрос просто добавит цвет с id `10001`, а ваш сначала удалит `10000` записей, а потом добавит эти же `10000` записей и ещё одну. Это же лишние действия, время и нагрузка. Кроме нагрузки на БД в вашем варианте сначала нужно эти пары ещё составить с помощью ЯП (языка программирования), это опять лишний код, время и дополнительная нагрузка

Comment: *ну вот были у продукта цвета с id* А вот теперь расскажите, откуда Вам это известно, если, по Вашему же признанию, "Откуда я должен знать, что сейчас находиться в базе?" *в вашем варианте сначала нужно эти пары ещё составить с помощью ЯП (языка программирования)* Да с какого перепугу-то? я просто удалю все записи для продукта, и мне вовсе не нужно знать, какие они там были, и есть ли какие-то из них в новом наборе. *лишний код, время и дополнительная нагрузка* Лишний код - это как раз Ваши дополнительные проверки. И, уж поверьте на слово, почти наверняка с ними время и нагрузка будут выше.

Comment: @Akina ну хз, хз, удалять 10.000 строк, потом добавлять 10.000 строк или 1 раз посмотреть, что есть в базе, по-моему тут всё очевидно, посмотреть, что есть в базе (мой вариант) намного быстрее =)

Comment: Мы говорим о реальной задаче или о теоретических выкладках? реально - хорошо если наберётся два-три десятка цветов, и уж точно не 10к. Нет, если Вам такое решение больше нравится - так пусть оно таким и будет. Но намекну. Для эффективной работы таблица должна быть индексирована по паре полей (продукт, цвет). В Вашем случае, с частичным удалением, скорее всего Вы получите кучу джойнов в страницах индекса, а при последующей вставке такую же кучу сплитов.

Answer (score 0):

Принципиально это выглядит так:

```sql
WITH cte AS ( DELETE FROM products_to_colors
              WHERE (product_id, color_id) IN ( {список пар на удаление} )
            )
INSERT INTO products_to_colors VALUES {список пар на вставку} ;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5c7d2db60ed75693dc70f4bc2b08fd01)

Comment: Интересно а если cte не использовать в запросе, то он выполнится? По идее вы только определили его

Comment: А вот как узнать список пар на вставку и удаление? Сначала выполнить `SELECT` запрос и посмотреть что в БД? Я думал без этого можно обойтись, вроде как с `DELETE` у меня получилось, `INSERT` не могу, есть функции `unnest` и `array_fill`, нельзя их как-то использовать, чтобы не увеличивать размер кода и количество запросов?

Comment: @AzizUmarov *а если cte не использовать в запросе, то он выполнится?* Вот не понял фразы, от слова "вообще". *По идее вы только определили его* Его - это, стесняюсь спросить, кого?

Comment: @Inventor *А вот как узнать список пар на вставку и удаление?* ??? *пришёл новый запрос и у продукта изменились цвета, например, продукт с id 7, теперь должен иметь цвета [1, 3, 5, 7], было [1, 2, 3, 4]* - это означает, что удалять надо (7,1),(7,2),(7,3),(7,4), а вставлять соответственно (7,1),(7,3),(7,5),(7,7). А если просто пришёл новый список, то удалять тупо все (7,*).

Comment: Вот смотрите With cte ... Select .. from cte Эквивалент select ... From (select ...) Если cte не использовать то каков его эквивалент

Comment: @AzizUmarov Нет, не эквивалент. И особенно не эквивалент в PostgreSQL.

Comment: @Akina ну я понимаю, но в реальных примерах, я же не знаю, что в БД, мне тогда это наверное нужно получить сначала с помощью `SELECT`? Я вот и спрашиваю, нельзя это как-то объединить в 1 запрос, чтобы уменьшить нагрузку на БД и количество запросов к ней? Использовать подзапросы уже в самом `INSERT` для получения данных, короче говоря

Comment: @Inventor *я же не знаю, что в БД* Я у кого-то уже, помнится, спрашивал, "как выглядят исходные данные ТОЧНО". А этот кто-то вместо точного ответа отделывается невнятными рассуждениями. Какая в пень разница, что там БЫЛО? Задача может быть одна из двух. Первый вариант указывает, что удалить, конкретные отдельные пары. Второй - ничего не указывает, просто требует удалить всё, что есть. Первый вариант рассмотрен в ответе, второй - описан в комментарии-ответе на Ваш комментарий. Если есть третий вариант, который я не учёл - ну опишите его, что ли...

Comment: @Akina какой смысл в вашем ответе, он работает только в 1 единственном случае, при 1 единственном сочетании значений. Откуда я должен знать, что сейчас находиться в базе? Видимо вы меня неправильно понял, ниже я представил своё решение

Comment: @Inventor *Видимо вы меня неправильно понял* Запросто. Я не зря задавал вопросы - и, признаться, ждал на них ответы. *он работает только в 1 единственном случае, при 1 единственном сочетании значений.* Это - шаблон, который применим к любому типу и сочетанию параметров. Небольшое изменение выражения отбора (только по продукту или по заданной паре продукт-цвет - это всё непринципиально), и только...